# Couldn't autowire. No beans of JacksonTester<Car>type found

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, api, backend

I've created a test case in a java CarControllerTest class, but for some odd reason, the test keeps failing. It gives me the following error:

```
"Could not autowire. No beans of JacksonTester<Car> type found."
```

A clear illustration of what is happening is shown at the image attached below:

[image]

Comment: No images of code please, because: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: In any case, I don't see any reason why JacksonTester would be available as a bean. Either you need to explicitly declare it as one (if you have, show the code where you do that), or you would need some kind of [autoconfiguration](https://medium.com/empathyco/how-spring-boot-autoconfiguration-works) provided by the library (i'm doubtful there is such a thing for what you're doing). Probably neither of these are the case, in which case, you can't autowire it. Just instantiate it normally: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/json/JacksonTester.html

Comment: @Michael there's now an image.

Comment: Michael, I tried following what you wrote still it wont work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?